# How to add custom autocomplete list to CodeMirror when config in python mode?

Tags: angular, codemirror

I can add items or change the whole autocomplete list of codemirror when I config in `mode: javascript` with the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
let orig = CodeMirror.hint.javascript;
CodeMirror.hint.javascript = function (cm) {
    var inner = orig(cm) || { from: cm.getCursor(), to: cm.getCursor(), list: [] };
    inner.list = ['test1', 'test2']
    return inner;
  };
}
```

but when I config in `mode: python` I don't know how to customize the autocomplete list eventhough there is an autocomplete list with the python keywords [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukky6c)